# Android Keyboard Navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, keyboard-navigation

I'm trying to implement keyboard navigation in Jetpack Compose.

Have a `LazyColumn` which contains some list elements as `Row{}` all the Row's are clickable and receive focus. What I'm trying to achieve is to scroll to next item in the list after reaching the bottom of the screen.

After pressing the DOWN arrow key / TAB key, the focus stops at the bottom of the screen and does not scroll down. Am I wrong to expect it to happen automatically ? Do we need to use key events and how can we use key events to support scrolling using keyboard with Jetpack Compose.

Code:

```
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = Spacing2X)
                .padding(top = Spacing2X)
        ) {
            items(SOME_LIST_HERE) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable { }) {
                    Text(text = "")
                }
            }
        }
```

Scenario Video: https://twitter.com/karan4c6/status/1479426842566094849

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `lazyListState` to achieve that. First, you need to create it using `val state = rememberLazyListState()` and then provide it to your `LazyColumn` as a parameter.

You then need to use `state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` on every focus change to see what items are currently visible, combine that knowledge with `state.firstVisibleItemIndex` and which item is currently focused, and use it to scroll accordingly.

It's a hacky solution involving handling of indexes, but I made it work. I've lost access to that project since, so I cannot provide you with the working example, sorry.